# How to pass method on LINQ-generated object as delegate?

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have the following method (where SetTypes is an enum):

```
public IEnumerable<Chart> RetrieveCharts(IEnumerable<string> filters, SetTypes set)
{
    switch (set)
    {
        case SetTypes.Set: return GetChartsSet(filters);
        case SetTypes.Subset: return GetChartsSubset(filters);
        // Other cases here...
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am duplicating code across my method calls ... the only thing that's changing is the method call on the HashSet instance:

```
private IEnumerable<Chart> GetChartsSet(IEnumerable<string> filters)
{
    using (var db = new ChartContext())
    {
        return db.Charts.Where(c => new HashSet<string>(c.ProductFilters.Select(f => f.Filter)).SetEquals(filters)).Select(c => c);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Chart> GetChartsSubset(IEnumerable<string> filters)
{
    using (var db = new ChartContext())
    {
        return db.Charts.Where(c => new HashSet<string>(c.ProductFilters.Select(f => f.Filter)).IsProperSubsetOf(filters)).Select(c => c);
    }
}
// More duplicated methods follow...
```

Instead of having multiple methods simply to call a different method on HashSet, I'd prefer a consolidated method which takes the HashSet method as an argument - but I'm not sure how to proceed.  How do I do this?

Bonus points if you also tell me how to get rid of that switch statement.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a common implementation that takes an additional [`Predicate<HashSet<string>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) on the set:

```
private IEnumerable<Chart> GetWithPredicate(Predicate<HashSet<string>> pred) {
    using (var db = new ChartContext()) {
        return db.Charts
            .Where(c => pred(new HashSet<string>(c.ProductFilters.Select(f => f.Filter))))
            .Select(c => c);
    }
}
```

and then reuse it in different methods:

```
private IEnumerable<Chart> GetChartsSet(IEnumerable<string> filters) {
    return GetWithPredicate(s => s.SetEquals(filters));
}

private IEnumerable<Chart> GetChartsSubset(IEnumerable<string> filters) {
    return GetWithPredicate(s => s.IsProperSubsetOf(filters));
}
```

Comment: Good use of Predicate delegate, but how does it helps in concise code, aren't you still calling GetChartsSet and GetChartsSubset separately. You would still need Enum type.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj This approach let OP share the `using ...` code among multiple methods that differ only in the specific predicate that they use to filter sets.